# vb.net- An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, vb.net

Criei um delete mas ao executar da-me o erro :

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException', ja procurei ajuda, mas tudo o que aparece é para #C, preciso de uma solução para VB.

Penso que o problema seja o facto da tabela defeito estar associada a um processo, da tabela processo. E o programa não deixa apagar para não deixar o processo "pendurado"...

```
 ' GET: DEF_DEFECT/Delete/5
    Function Delete(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        Dim dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT = db.DEF_DEFECT.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(dEF_DEFECT) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View(dEF_DEFECT)
    End Function

    ' POST: DEF_DEFECT/Delete/5
    <HttpPost()>
    <ActionName("Delete")>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT = db.DEF_DEFECT.Find(id)
        db.DEF_DEFECT.Remove(dEF_DEFECT)
        db.SaveChanges()
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End Function
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a mensagem da exceção?

Comment: Editei para acrescentar foto do erro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Através do [forum ASP.NET](https://forums.asp.net/t/2131288.aspx)cheguei á conclusão que deveria mudar o código para:

```
' POST: DEF_DEFECT/Delete/5
    <HttpPost()>
    <ActionName("Delete")>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT = db.DEF_DEFECT.Find(id)
        For Each pRO_PROCESS In dEF_DEFECT.PRO_PROCESS
            db.PRO_PROCESS.Remove(pRO_PROCESS)
            db.DEF_DEFECT.Remove(dEF_DEFECT)
            db.SaveChanges()

        Next
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End Function`
```

Mas o erro persistia, depois de muito investigar, apercebi-me que o problema não era só a relação dos defeitos com os processsos, mas obviamente que tambem tinha a relação dos defeitos com as causas.
Portanto alterei o código para:

```
' POST: DEF_DEFECT/Delete/5
    <HttpPost()>
    <ActionName("Delete")>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As String) As ActionResult
        Dim dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT = db.DEF_DEFECT.Find(id)

        If dEF_DEFECT.PRO_PROCESS.Count = 0 And dEF_DEFECT.CAU_CAUSE.Count = 0 Then
            db.DEF_DEFECT.Remove(dEF_DEFECT)
            db.SaveChanges()
        Else
            Dim deleteListCauses As List(Of FMEA_MVC.CAU_CAUSE) = New List(Of FMEA_MVC.CAU_CAUSE)
            deleteListCauses = dEF_DEFECT.CAU_CAUSE.ToList()
            For item As Integer = 0 To deleteListCauses.Count - 1 Step 1
                dEF_DEFECT.CAU_CAUSE.Remove(deleteListCauses(item))
            Next
            Dim deleteListItems As List(Of FMEA_MVC.PRO_PROCESS) = New List(Of FMEA_MVC.PRO_PROCESS)
            deleteListItems = dEF_DEFECT.PRO_PROCESS.ToList()

            For item As Integer = 0 To deleteListItems.Count - 1 Step 1
                dEF_DEFECT.PRO_PROCESS.Remove(deleteListItems(item))
            Next
            MsgBox("You have one or more processes and causes associated" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(13) & "Are you sure you want to delete them?", vbYesNo, "Delete Defect")
            db.DEF_DEFECT.Remove(dEF_DEFECT)
            db.SaveChanges()
        End If

        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End Function
```

E problema resolvido :D